# PHP Создать директорию выше

Tags: php

как средствами PHP создать папку выше корня сайта, для хранения в ней необходимых данных?

полный путь: home/user111/site.ru/index.php
нужно создать папку в user111.

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Если ограничений по правам или настройкам php нет, то `../имя-папки` указывает имя в предыдущем каталоге от текущего. Создать папку:

```
mkdir("../NewDirectory");
```

кроме того можно поменять текущий каталог с помощью `chdir`.